# Before event for the bootstrap on-off switch plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the bootstrap toggle plugin. However I want to ask for confirmation before the status actually of the button actually changes. I tried that .change event. However, it changes the status of the toggle button before I can open the confirmation box. Can you please let me know what can be done?

Here is the HTML:

```
<input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">

<div class="modal fade" id="modalTurnOff" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTurnOff" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Are you sure you want to close your account?</h5>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       Lorem Ipsum
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">No, Keep active Status </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary js-change-status" data-type='0'>Yes, close it</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is JS I am using:

```
<script> 
$('#toggle-event').on("change", function() {
    $("#modalTurnOff").modal();
});
</script>
```

But the problem is as soon as I click on the toggle button, it changes status.

Comment: why not do something like $('#id').on('change', function(){ // display modal {}); Then attach the event to the confirmation button in the modal?

Comment: That's exactly what I did. However, the button changes status BEFORE the modal for is even shown. and there seems to be no way to cancel the toggle as well.

Comment: can you show what html you're using?

Comment: I edited my question with HTML and JS.

Comment: just using bootstrap css i take it?

Comment: Yes with bootstrap-toggle.min.css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153893/discussion-between-keith-and-amit-joshi).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with. On your toggle event, you just make sure that the toggle has class "off" and when you do your AJAX call, you remove it.

https://jsfiddle.net/0errvdeu/2/

```
$('#toggle-event').on("change", function(e) {
    var isClicked = $('#toggle-event').is(':checked');
    if(isClicked == true){
         $('#modalTurnOff').show();
         $('.toggle').addClass('off');
    }
});
```